# Setup pointer to 2D array, then passing that pointer into a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing

G'day all,

I know this has been discussed a lot, but I still cant find what I need. I am pretty new to C and still am getting my head around pointers, namely, pointers to multi-dimensional arrays.

I have looked at examples such as `int a[2][3]; int (*p) = a` when a is a 2D array, but what does the brackets do?

I am creating a program which has a 2D array as a variable and it needs to pass that array onto an external function to modify it.

My array is initilised like this:

`unsigned int node[3][2]={   {PINB,PINC},  {0,0},  {0,0}   };`

I believe the best way to do this is through pointers but I don't know how to setup the prototype for my function that takes in the 2D array.

This is the function im passing it to and how I call it:

`NodeToMIDI(node, i, pMIDIdata);`

And this is its prototype: //where "node_pointer" is the 2D array arg.

`void NodeToMIDI(unsigned int node_pointer, unsigned int node_select, unsigned int * MidiPacket);`

Can someone please explain the syntax and logic behind how to do this. Some of the other threads I have looked at have syntax that is unknown to me. Such as `int ** a` for example.

Thank-you for any help!
Andrew.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the array to function naturally only if you know (at compilation-time) the size of the inner array.

The examples you saw, are probably `int a[2][3]; int (*p)[3] = a`. The brackets means that `p` is pointer to array of 3 ints, not array of 3 pointers to int. Since you can dereference pointers like arrays, you can use `p` as if it was an array of arrays of 3 ints (which `a` is).

In the same way, you can write a prototype like `void myfunc(int (*arr)[3]);` - If you pass `a` to this function, it's exactly the same thing like pass array to function that gets pointer.

There is another way to write this prototype: `void myfunc(int arr[][3]);` - The compiler will understand it in the same way, and some people find this writing more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

The signature you are looking for is:

```
void NodeToMIDI(unsigned node_pointer[][2], unsigned node_select, unsigned * MidiPacket);
```

which you would call

```
NodeToMIDI(node, /*something*/, /*something else*/);
```

Answer (score -1):

Some background information:

An array behaves a bit like a pointer. if you have `char* name = {"John"};` you can access the characters with name[2] = h for example.
Also name[0] (the first element) is the same like you use the pointer name directly. The pointer `name` refers to the adress of the first element in the array.

So an array of on array is... a pointer to a pointer. This looks like that what you described.

```
int ** a;
```

So this is an int pointer which referes to another int pointer which refers to a specific adress.

So you can take `unsigned int** arrayOfArray` as a function parameter.
Then you can access the element like you know it from arrays.

```
arrayOfArray[0][2] = 42;
```